# encode object to bytes by golang unsafe?

Tags: go

```
func Encode(i interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 1024))
    // size := unsafe.Sizeof(i)
    size := reflect.TypeOf(i).Size()
    fmt.Println(size)
    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&i)
    startAddr := uintptr(ptr)
    endAddr := startAddr + size
    for i := startAddr; i < endAddr; i++ {
        bytePtr := unsafe.Pointer(i)
        b := *(*byte)(bytePtr)
        buffer.WriteByte(b)
    }
    return buffer.Bytes(), nil
}

func TestEncode(t *testing.T) {
    test := Test{10, "hello world"}
    b, _ := Encode(test)
    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&b)
    newTest := *(*Test)(ptr)
    fmt.Println(newTest.X)
}
```

I am learning how to use golang unsafe and wrote this function for encoding any object. I meet with two problems, first, dose unsafe.Sizeof(obj) always return obj's pointer size? Why it different from  reflect.TypeOf(obj).Size()? Second, I want to iterate the underlying bytes of obj and convert it back to obj in TestEncode function by unsafe.Pointer(), but the object's values all corrupt, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `unsafe.Sizeof` returns the bytes that needs to store the type. It is a little bit tricky, but it does not mean bytes that needs to store the data.

For example, a slice, as it is well known, stores 3 4-byte ints on a 32bit machine. One uintptr for memory address of the underlying array, and two `int32` for `len` and `cap`. So no matter how long a slice is or what type it is of, a slice takes always 12 bytes on a 32 bit machine. Likely, a string uses 8 bytes: 1 `uintptr` for address and 1 `int32` for `len`.

As for difference between `reflect.TypeOf().Size`, it is about interface. `reflect.TypeOf` looks into the interface and gets an concrete type, and reports bytes needed about the concrete type, while `unsafe.Sizeof` just returns 8 for an interface type: 2 `uintptr` for a pointer to the data and a pointer to the method lists.

Second part is quite clear now. For one, `unsafe.Pointer` is taking the address of the interface, instead of the concrete type. Two, in `TestEncode`, `unsafe.Pointer` is taking address to the 12-byte slice "header". There might be other errors, but with the two mentioned, they are meaningless to spot.

Note: I avoid talking about orders of the `uintptr` and `int32` not only because I don't know, but also becuase they are not documented, unsafe, and implentation depended.

Note 2: Conclusion: Don't try to dump memory of a Go data.

Note 3: I change everything to 32 bit becuase playground is using it, so it is easier to check.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But I think there is a typo in your answer, a slice should stores 3 8-byte ints on a 64bit machine, right?

Comment: Yes it is a typo. I will fix it when I am not on mobile.